# hacer registros de la base de datos en servidor local y remoto

Tags: php, java, jquery, postgresql, redes

Cómo puedo hacer dos conexiones a la vez, es decir, hago un registro de la base de datos a mi servidor y automáticamente esto también haga registro en la base de datos local.

Lo que trato de hacer es que en mi servidor local también se guarde la información que se hace en el servidor remoto y se mantenga actualizado

```
ejemplo host local
host: 'localhost';
```

y

```
host remoto o del servidor
host:'192.168.1.1'
```

Comment: Exactamente para que quieres hacer eso? con que motivo? que estás buscando un respaldo local? o es por histórico o exactamente para que podrías ser mas explicito? Saludos

Comment: si es como respaldo local y al consultar mi informacion localmente yo pueda ver lo mismo lo que veo en el servidor remoto, es para que cuando yo no tenga internet en mi servidor remoto pueda trabajar localmente y al conectarse a internet esta informacion se cargue automaticamente al servidor remoto

Comment: En que versión de PostgreSQL se quieren implementar?

Comment: es la version 11.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si necesita múltiples conexiones abiertas a la vez, simplemente puede crear múltiples instancias de PDO:

```
try {
  $db1 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=base1;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
  $db2 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=base2;host=otroservidor', 'username', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

**Recuerda tener habilitado en PHP, la extensión para Postgre**

**Para conectarse a PostgreSQL utilizando funciones nativas:**

Use el siguiente código PHP para conectarse a PostgreSQL y seleccionar una base de datos. Reemplace USERNAME con su nombre de usuario, PASSWORD con su contraseña y DBNAME con el nombre de la base de datos:

```
<?php
    $db_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=DBNAME user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD");
?>
```

**Conéctese a PostgreSQL usando PDO (PHP Data Objects)**

Las funciones de PostgreSQL en el procedimiento anterior solo se pueden usar con bases de datos PostgreSQL. PDO abstrae el acceso a la base de datos y le permite usar código que puede manejar diferentes tipos de bases de datos.

Para conectarse a PostgreSQL usando PDO:

Use el siguiente código PHP para conectarse a PostgreSQL y seleccionar una base de datos. Reemplace USERNAME con su nombre de usuario, PASSWORD con su contraseña y DBNAME con el nombre de la base de datos:

```
<?php
    $myPDO = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
?>
```

Comment: Bien nadamas que no sabemos si es PHP lo que usa ya que como notas en las tags, también coloca java y en el caso del gestor coloca postgresql y no mysql

Comment: gracias por tu comentario, hare la prueba

Comment: espero que te haya funcionado, cualquier cosa me comentás

Comment: como seria sin ocupar PDO y usar solo php con postgresql?

Comment: edite mi respuesta, otra duda comentame

Comment: gracias, cualquier duda te aviso

Comment: con esto ya se puede replicar la base de datos local y remota? , esa es mi duda y como hago para que no choquen las dos bases de datos cuando abra mi pagina al navegador

Comment: probaste lo anterior?